How can I filter available time slots between booked appointments in PostgreSQL?
I am trying to implement an appointment manager for a dentist office.
Thing is I am not sure how to properly implement such function. Right now I have managed to create these two tables that will handle it:
CREATE TABLE Horarios (
    id_horario BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    hora TIME UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Consultas (
    id_consulta BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    paciente INTEGER REFERENCES Pacientes(id_paciente),
    creado_por INTEGER REFERENCES Administrativo(id_administrativo),
    fecha_designada DATE NOT NULL,
    consulta_completa BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
    hora_inic INTEGER REFERENCES Horarios(id_horario),
    hora_fin INTEGER REFERENCES Horarios(id_horario),
    dentista INTEGER REFERENCES Dentistas(id_dentista)
);

All hour timestamps are hardcoded values like ("07:00")
So far, its all good I have been using this query to fetch all availables appointments:
SELECT
    h.id_horario,
    h.hora 
FROM 
    Horarios h
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Consultas c
        WHERE
            c.fecha_designada = $1
            AND c.dentista = $2
            AND h.hora >= (SELECT hora FROM Horarios WHERE id_horario = c.hora_inic)
            AND h.hora < (SELECT hora FROM Horarios WHERE id_horario = c.hora_fin)
    )
ORDER BY
    h.hora;

It will check for all, timestamps that are between the start_hour(hora_inic) and the end_hour(hora_fin) of said appointment.
And it works great when you have to create appointments in advance.
But when you have to create lets say:
An appointment from 7:00 to 7:30 and then another from 8:00 to 8:30 it doesn't let me create an appointment from 7:30 to 8:00.
Now this is obviously a logical error.
I have been trying to change my query and both my backend and frontend. in order to aliviate this problem. But I believe this is just poorly design on my part.
I could use some guidance or advice in how to fix this or how to create an appointment app. Since thats the part that giving me issues right now.
Appreciate the time it took you to read my post. Thank you!

It's good you have provided the create table commands. Please add also some insert commands to create sample data and add the expected result as table in your question.

Advice: Use a tsrange datatype and an exclusion constraint. That is much easier and avoids overlapping appointments. Complete examples can be found in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

I would change the data model and use the data type tstzrange. That gives you the option to add a constraint to avoid overlapping appointments.
Here is a complete example where multiple dentists can have an appointment with a single patient. The working hours and days are in the SELECT statement, in the WHERE condition. Also, the length of an appointment is there; it's now set at 30 minutes.
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

CREATE TABLE dentist(id_dentist INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                , name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE appointment(
    id_appointment INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    id_patient INT NOT NULL, -- foreign key to "patient" table
    id_dentist INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dentist(id_dentist),
    appointment tstzrange NOT NULL,
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (id_dentist WITH =, appointment WITH &&)
);

SET TIMEZONE TO 'America/Los_Angeles';

INSERT INTO dentist(name) VALUES ('Fulano'), ('Beltrano'), ('Sicrano');

INSERT INTO appointment(id_patient, id_dentist, appointment)
VALUES (1, 1, tstzrange('2024-11-01 14:00 -07:00', '2024-11-01 14:30 -07:00'));

INSERT INTO appointment(id_patient, id_dentist, appointment)
VALUES (2, 2, tstzrange('2024-11-01 14:00 -07:00', '2024-11-01 14:30 -07:00'));

INSERT INTO appointment(id_patient, id_dentist, appointment)
VALUES (3, 3, tstzrange('2024-11-01 13:00 -07:00', '2024-11-01 13:30 -07:00'));

INSERT INTO appointment(id_patient, id_dentist, appointment)
VALUES (3, 3, tstzrange('2024-11-01 13:30 -07:00', '2024-11-01 14:00 -07:00'));

SELECT id_dentist
     , tstzrange(working_hours, working_hours + INTERVAL '30 minutes') AS available_time_slot
FROM generate_series(
        date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp) + INTERVAL '30 minutes'
        , current_timestamp + INTERVAL '14 DAYS', INTERVAL '30 minutes' -- just the next 14 days
     ) gs(working_hours) -- 30 minutes for each consult
    , dentist -- get all dentists
WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM working_hours) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
AND (   working_hours::TIME BETWEEN '08:00' AND '11:30' -- start time of the consult
    OR  working_hours::TIME BETWEEN '13:00' AND '17:30' -- start time of the consult
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (    SELECT 1
                    FROM appointment
                    WHERE appointment.id_dentist = dentist.id_dentist
                      AND appointment @> working_hours)
ORDER BY 2,1;

When you need two dentists for a single appointment, just use an aggregate in combination with HAVING:
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id_dentist ORDER BY id_dentist) AS available_dentists
     , tstzrange(working_hours, working_hours + INTERVAL '30 minutes') AS available_time_slot
FROM generate_series(
        date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp) + INTERVAL '30 minutes'
        , current_timestamp + INTERVAL '14 DAYS', INTERVAL '30 minutes' -- just the next 14 days
     ) gs(working_hours) -- 30 minutes for each consult
    , dentist -- get all dentists
WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM working_hours) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
AND (   working_hours::TIME BETWEEN '08:00' AND '11:30' -- start time of the consult
    OR  working_hours::TIME BETWEEN '13:00' AND '17:30' -- start time of the consult
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (    SELECT 1
                    FROM appointment
                    WHERE appointment.id_dentist = dentist.id_dentist
                      AND appointment @> working_hours)
GROUP BY 2
HAVING COUNT(id_dentist) >= 2
ORDER BY 2;


From mentally reviewing the code, nothing seems to be wrong. I would need to run some sample queries to see what the inner query is returning to debug that. Do not do the "SELECT 1", do a "SELECT *" and replace the h.hora value with '7:30'.
But...
The choice of creating a table to define hours strikes me as odd. You do not need a list of which hours exist in a day. You know they can go from 00:00 to 23:59; you do not need to validate the values.
More than a master of "hours", the usual way for this is to have a table of "slots" (which might be free or reserved). Each slot has its own fixed starting and ending time. The main downside is that it limits flexibility, if the appointments are of different duration; you can work around this by grouping several slots (either by business logic or creating an 1-N "appointment" class). Also, you need a procedure to generate the slots periodically.
The benefits are numerous:

The query for free slots (which is one of the most frequent you will run) becomes way easier and faster.
You have flexibility. If you want to change working hours, you just generate the slots differently. What happens with your current model if you no longer want to schedule appointments at 8:00? You cannot delete the 8:00 record, because you have lots of previous appointments that reference it.


Tryed to guess the basic data structure and to offer a solution accordingly...
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
CREATE TABLE Horarios (
    id_horario BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    hora TIME UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
Insert Into    Horarios (id_horario, hora)
  ( Select   1,    '07:00'::TIME Union All 
    Select   2,    '07:30'::TIME Union All
    Select   3,    '08:00'::TIME Union All
    Select   4,    '08:30'::TIME Union All
    Select   5,    '09:00'::TIME Union All
    Select   6,    '09:30'::TIME Union All
    Select   7,    '10:00'::TIME Union All
    Select   8,    '10:30'::TIME Union All
    Select   9,    '11:00'::TIME Union All
    Select  10,    '11:30'::TIME Union All
    Select  11,    '12:00'::TIME 
    ... ...
    ... ...
);




id_horario
hora




1
07:00:00


2
07:30:00


3
08:00:00


4
08:30:00


5
09:00:00


6
09:30:00


7
10:00:00


8
10:30:00


9
11:00:00


10
11:30:00


11
12:00:00



--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
CREATE TABLE Consultas (
    id_consulta BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    paciente INTEGER,
    creado_por INTEGER,
    fecha_designada DATE NOT NULL,
    consulta_completa BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
    hora_inic INTEGER REFERENCES Horarios(id_horario),
    hora_fin INTEGER REFERENCES Horarios(id_horario),
    dentista INTEGER
);
Insert Into Consultas (id_consulta, paciente, creado_por, fecha_designada, 
                       consulta_completa, hora_inic, hora_fin, dentista)
  ( Select     101, 1001, 11, '2024-10-24'::DATE, 
               False, 1, 3, 1 Union All
    Select     102, 1002, 11, '2024-10-24'::DATE, 
               False, 7, 8, 1 Union All
    Select     103, 1003, 11, '2024-10-24'::DATE, 
               False, 3, 4, 2 Union All
    Select     104, 1004, 13, '2024-10-24'::DATE, 
               False, 4, 5, 2 
    ... ...
    ... ...
  );




id_consulta
paciente
creado_por
fecha_designada
consulta_completa
hora_inic
hora_fin
dentista




101
1001
11
2024-10-24
f
1
3
1


102
1002
11
2024-10-24
f
7
8
1


103
1003
11
2024-10-24
f
3
4
2


104
1004
13
2024-10-24
f
4
5
2



... added  cte  with  dentistas  to work with their hours individualy ...
The grid cte prepares the data for later aggregations defining the ocupied and available periods as well as mixed groupings
WITH
  dentistas AS
    ( Select 1 as dentista, 'dentista 1' as nombre Union All
      Select 2 as dentista, 'dentista 2' as nombre  
    ),
  grid AS 
    ( Select        '2024-10-24'::DATE as fecha, -- this is supposed to be a calendar date
                    d.dentista, d.nombre,
                    h.id_horario, h.hora, 
                    c.hora_inic, c.hora_fin, 
                    Case When Coalesce(c.hora_inic, c.hora_fin) Is Null
                         Then 'Disponible'
                    Else 'Ocupado'
                    End as estado, 
               CASE WHEN ( c.hora_inic Is NOT Null And 
                           LAG(c.hora_fin) Over(Partition By d.dentista Order By h.id_horario) Is Null )
                      OR ( c.hora_inic Is Null And 
                           LAG(c.hora_fin) Over(Partition By d.dentista Order By h.id_horario) Is NOT Null )
                    Then h.id_horario
               END as grupo
      From          dentistas d
      Inner Join    Horarios h ON( 1 = 1 )
      Left Join     Consultas c ON( c.dentista = d.dentista And 
                                    h.id_horario Between c.hora_inic And c.hora_fin )
    --  Where       fecha = '2024-10-24'    -- this is supposed to be a calendar date
      Order By      d.dentista, h.id_horario, c.hora_inic
    )

--      M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT  x.fecha, x.dentista, x.nombre, x.estado, 
        Min(id_horario) as hora_inic_id, Min(hora) as hora_inic, 
        Max(id_horario) as hora_fin_id, Max(hora) as hora_fin
FROM ( Select    fecha, dentista, nombre, id_horario, hora, hora_inic, hora_fin, estado, 
                 Max(Grupo) Over(Partition By dentista Order By id_horario
                            Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as grupo
       From      grid
       Order By  dentista, id_horario
     ) x
GROUP BY x.fecha, x.dentista, x.nombre, x.grupo, x.estado 
ORDER BY x.fecha, x.dentista, x.nombre, Min(id_horario), x.grupo, x.estado 

R e s u l t :



fecha
dentista
nombre
estado
hora_inic_id
hora_inic
hora_fin_id
hora_fin




2024-10-24
1
dentista 1
Ocupado
1
07:00:00
3
08:00:00


2024-10-24
1
dentista 1
Disponible
4
08:30:00
6
09:30:00


2024-10-24
1
dentista 1
Ocupado
7
10:00:00
8
10:30:00


2024-10-24
1
dentista 1
Disponible
9
11:00:00
11
12:00:00


2024-10-24
2
dentista 2
Disponible
1
07:00:00
2
07:30:00


2024-10-24
2
dentista 2
Ocupado
3
08:00:00
5
09:00:00


2024-10-24
2
dentista 2
Disponible
6
09:30:00
11
12:00:00



fiddle
The above resultset should give you both - the periods of availability and the periods that are already occupied - and you can filter it as you wish ...
... to get the availability hours you just need to filter the Main SQL's outer query with Where clause like below:
...
WHERE    x.estado = 'Disponible' 
...

R e s u l t :



fecha
dentista
nombre
estado
hora_inic_id
hora_inic
hora_fin_id
hora_fin




2024-10-24
1
dentista 1
Disponible
4
08:30:00
6
09:30:00


2024-10-24
1
dentista 1
Disponible
9
11:00:00
11
12:00:00


2024-10-24
2
dentista 2
Disponible
1
07:00:00
2
07:30:00


2024-10-24
2
dentista 2
Disponible
6
09:30:00
11
12:00:00



